# How to configure my token to have 1000000 SUPPLY?

Tags: solidity

can you help me, I want my token to have 1000000 SUPPLY, can you tell me if everything is fine as it is, or do I have to change something?

```
contract Mirage is Context, IERC20, Ownable {
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    using Address for address;
    mapping (address => uint256) private _rOwned;
    mapping (address => uint256) private _tOwned;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) private _allowances;
    mapping (address => bool) private _isExcludedFromFee;
    mapping (address => bool) private _isExcluded;
    address[] private _excluded;
    address private _developmentWalletAddress = 0x1B5Ef6DDf4c06784c57d4f000000000;
    uint256 private constant MAX = ~uint256(0);
    uint256 private _tTotal = 1000000 * 10**18;
    uint256 private _rTotal = (MAX - (MAX % _tTotal));
    uint256 private _tFeeTotal;
    string private _name = "Mirage";
    string private _symbol = "MIR";
    uint8 private _decimals = 8;
    uint256 public _taxFee = 10;
    uint256 private _previousTaxFee = _taxFee;
    uint256 public _developmentFee = 10;
    uint256 private _previousDevelopmentFee = _developmentFee;
    uint256 public _liquidityFee = 10;
    uint256 private _previousLiquidityFee = _liquidityFee;

    IUniswapV2Router02 public immutable uniswapV2Router;
    address public immutable uniswapV2Pair;
    bool inSwapAndLiquify;
    bool public swapAndLiquifyEnabled = true;
    uint256 public _maxTxAmount = 1000000 * 10**18;
    uint256 private numTokensSellToAddToLiquidity = 1000000 * 10**18;

    event MinTokensBeforeSwapUpdated(uint256 minTokensBeforeSwap);
    event SwapAndLiquifyEnabledUpdated(bool enabled);
    event SwapAndLiquify(
        uint256 tokensSwapped,
        uint256 ethReceived,
        uint256 tokensIntoLiqudity
```

Comment: The constructor is missing without more details we can't say anything about the supply calculations.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it to **1000000** this way.

```
contract Mirage is Context, IERC20, Ownable {
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    using Address for address;

    mapping (address => uint256) private _rOwned;
    mapping (address => uint256) private _tOwned;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) private _allowances;
    mapping (address => bool) private _isExcludedFromFee;
    mapping (address => bool) private _isExcluded;
    address[] private _excluded;
    address private _developmentWalletAddress = 0x1B5Ef6DDf4c06784c57d4f000000000;

    uint256 private constant MAX = ~uint256(0);
    uint256 private _tTotal = 1000000 * 10**18; // Change total supply here
    uint256 private _rTotal = (MAX - (MAX % _tTotal));
    uint256 private _tFeeTotal;
    string private _name = "Mirage";
    string private _symbol = "MIR";
    uint8 private _decimals = 18; //Set decimal places to 18
    uint256 public _taxFee = 10;
    uint256 private _previousTaxFee = _taxFee;
    uint256 public _developmentFee = 10;
    uint256 private _previousDevelopmentFee = _developmentFee;
    uint256 public _liquidityFee = 10;
    uint256 private _previousLiquidityFee = _liquidityFee;

    IUniswapV2Router02 public immutable uniswapV2Router;
    address public immutable uniswapV2Pair;
    bool inSwapAndLiquify;
    bool public swapAndLiquifyEnabled = true;
    uint256 public _maxTxAmount = 1000000 * 10**18;
    uint256 private numTokensSellToAddToLiquidity = 1000000 * 10**18;

    event MinTokensBeforeSwapUpdated(uint256 minTokensBeforeSwap);
    event SwapAndLiquifyEnabledUpdated(bool enabled);
    event SwapAndLiquify(
        uint256 tokensSwapped,
        uint256 ethReceived,
        uint256 tokensIntoLiquidity
    );
}
```